# Node.js - Static fileserver not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I'm trying to create a static fileserver in note.js, but it is not really working.

My fileserver.js code:

```
var http = require("http"), 
sys = require("sys"),
path = require("path"),
url = require("url"),
filesys = require("fs"),
rootpath = "D:\\NodeJS\\WWW\\",   
port = 3000; 

http.createServer(function(request,response){ 

var my_path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
var full_path = path.join(process.cwd(),rootpath+my_path); 

path.exists(full_path,function(exists){ 

    if(!exists){
        response.writeHeader(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});  
        response.write("404 Not Found\n");  
        response.end();
    }
    else{
        filesys.readFile(full_path, "binary", function(err, file) {  
             if(err) {  
                 response.writeHeader(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});  
                 response.write(err + "\n");  
                 response.end();  

             }  
             else{
                response.writeHeader(200);  
                response.write(file, "binary");  
                response.end();
            }    
          });
     });
   }) 

http.createServer(function(request,response){
    var my_path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    filesys.readFile(rootpath + my_path,response);
}).listen(port);

sys.puts("Server Running on 3000");
```

When I now try to open: localhost:3000/index.html (The index file is in the folder WWW), my webbrowser is just loading and loading something but not displaying anything. There is also no error in the console.

I hope you can help me!

JS

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get directory listing with this program? If yes then use this.

```
var http = require('http');
var connect = require('connect');

var app = connect()
  .use('/public', connect.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  .use('/public', connect.directory(__dirname + '/public'))
  .use(function(req, res){
    res.end('hello world\n');
  })

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);

// access it on http://localhost:3000/public
```

I have used connect module. `connect.directory` serves the directory listing and `connect.static` serves the static file.

Let me know if I have not understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var path = require("path");
var url = require("url");
var settings = require("../settings");


http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    var filetype = (uri.split("/static/")[1]).split(".")[1];
    var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);
    fs.readFile(filename, function (error, content) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(500);
            response.end();
        }
        else {

                response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': settings.STATIC.HEADERS[filetype.toUpperCase()] });
                response.end(content, 'utf-8');

            }

    });

}).listen(8000);
```

Add A settings File with something like this  :

```
module.exports = {
    DOMAIN: "localhost", // Runnimg Domain , Production Only
    PORT: 8080, // Port Project Running On
    PROJECT: __dirname, // project directory
    DEFAULT_THEME: "default", // Default Theme for site
    DB: { // Database Information and Credintials
        HOST: "localhost",
        USER: 'root',
        PASSWORD: 'root',
        DATABASE: 'sockets'
    },
    STATIC: { // Static Files and forlders information
        EXTENSIONS: ['psd', 'docs', 'zip', 'rar', 'png'],  // allowed to download extensions
        HEADERS: {// MIME Types for diffrent types
            PDF: 'application/pdf',
            CSS: 'text/css',
            JS: 'text/javascript',
            HTML: 'text/html',
            TXT: 'text/plain',
            JPG: 'image/jpeg',
            JPEG: 'image/jpeg',
            GIF: 'image/gif ',
            DOWNLOAD: 'application/octet-stream'
        }
    }
};
```

i Always like to have this file with everything that i will use everywhere.

and as you can see the code waits for a url like this :

```
http://domain:port/static/file.ext
```

you can change that in this line :

```
var filetype = (uri.split("/static/")[1]).split(".")[1];
```

Hope this helps